# How to list most popular post

Tags: query-posts

I want list the popular posts.popular post is defined by number of comments.If number of comment is high it will consider as popular.

How can i do this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily sort by native post fields, so try something like this:

```
$posts  = get_posts( array(
                 'numberposts' => 10,
                 'orderby' => 'comment_count',
                 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste the following code, where you want to display the popular posts

```
$popular = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, post_title, comment_count FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type='post' ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 10");

<ul>
foreach($popular as $posts) : ?>
<li> <?php echo $posts->post_title; ?> </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

make a try on [WordPress Popular Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/) Plugin. In this Plugin we having the option to sort with comment for popular post.:)